# No space between search options

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, user-interface

Check out [this search example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20closed%3Ano%20answers%3A0%20views%3A1000). It looks like an absolute mess above the search bar:

[image: No space between search options - it looks like this: "not closedviews>= 1000answers 0"]

It would be much better if the options were separated with commas and spaces:

> not closed, views>=1000, answers 0

Comment: when you concat strings without putting them spaces

Comment: Cross site duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305919/search-options-are-not-separated-with-spaces

Comment: This has been fixed, as [this MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306659/364493) states.